# Hadoop writable readFields EOFException

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, writable

I am implementing my own Writable for Hadoop secondary sort, but when running the job, Hadoop keeps throwing EOFException in my `readFields` method and I don't know what's wrong with it.

Error stack trace:

```
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:559)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.EOFException
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator.compare(WritableComparator.java:165)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKeyValue(ReduceContextImpl.java:158)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.ReduceContextImpl.nextKey(ReduceContextImpl.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.reduce.WrappedReducer$Context.nextKey(WrappedReducer.java:302)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.run(Reducer.java:170)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runNewReducer(ReduceTask.java:628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:390)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$ReduceTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:347)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable.readFields(IntWritable.java:47)
    at writable.WikiWritable.readFields(WikiWritable.java:39)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableComparator.compare(WritableComparator.java:158)
    ... 12 more
```

My code:

```
package writable;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;

import java.io.DataInput;
import java.io.DataOutput;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WikiWritable implements WritableComparable<WikiWritable> {
  private IntWritable docId;
  private IntWritable position;

  public WikiWritable() {
    this.docId = new IntWritable();
    this.position = new IntWritable();
  }

  public void set(String docId, int position) {
    this.docId = new IntWritable(Integer.valueOf(docId));
    this.position = new IntWritable(position);
  }

  @Override
  public int compareTo(WikiWritable o) {
    int result = this.docId.compareTo(o.docId);
    result = result == 0 ? this.position.compareTo(o.position) : result;
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public void write(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {
    docId.write(dataOutput);
    position.write(dataOutput); // error here
  }

  @Override
  public void readFields(DataInput dataInput) throws IOException {
    docId.readFields(dataInput);
    position.readFields(dataInput);
  }

  public IntWritable getDocId() {
    return docId;
  }

  public int getPosition() {
    return Integer.valueOf(position.toString());
  }
}

// Driver
public class Driver {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
    Path wiki = new Path(args[0]);
    Path out = new Path(args[1]);

    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "myjob");

    TextInputFormat.addInputPath(job, wiki);
    TextOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

    job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setMapOutputValueClass(WikiWritable.class);

    job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
    job.setMapperClass(WordMapper.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
    job.setReducerClass(WordReducer.class);
    job.setPartitionerClass(WikiPartitioner.class);
    job.setGroupingComparatorClass(WikiComparator.class);

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
  }
}

// Mapper.map
protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String[] words = value.toString().split(",");
    String id = words[0];
    String[] contents = words[3].toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^a-z]+", " ").split("\\s+");

    for (int i = 0; i < contents.length; i++) {
      String word = contents[i].trim();
      word = stem(word);
      WikiWritable output = new WikiWritable();
      output.set(id, i);
      context.write(new Text(contents[i]), output);
    }
  }

// Comparator
public class WikiComparator extends WritableComparator {
  public WikiComparator() {
    super(WikiWritable.class, true);
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(WritableComparable wc1, WritableComparable wc2) {
    WikiWritable w1 = (WikiWritable) wc1;
    WikiWritable w2 = (WikiWritable) wc2;
    return w1.compareTo(w2);
  }
}

// Partitioner
public class WikiPartitioner extends Partitioner<WikiWritable, Text> {
  @Override
  public int getPartition(WikiWritable wikiWritable, Text text, int i) {
    return Math.abs(wikiWritable.getDocId().hashCode() % i);
  }
}

// Reducer
public class WordReducer extends Reducer<Text, WikiWritable, Text, Text> {
  @Override
  protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<WikiWritable> values, Context ctx) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Map<String, StringBuilder> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (WikiWritable w : values) {
      String id = String.valueOf(w.getDocId());
      if (map.containsKey(id)) {
        map.get(id).append(w.getPosition()).append(".");
      } else {
        map.put(id, new StringBuilder());
        map.get(id).append(".").append(w.getPosition()).append(".");
      }
    }

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    map.keySet().forEach((k) -> {
      map.get(k).deleteCharAt(map.get(k).length() - 1);
      builder.append(k).append(map.get(k)).append(";");
    });

    ctx.write(key, new Text(builder.toString()));
  }
}
```

When constructing a new `WikiWritable`, the mapper first calls `new WikiWritable()` and then calls `set(...)`.

I tried changing `docId` and `position` to String and Integer and use `dataOutput.read()` (I forgot the exact method name but it's something similar) and still doesn't work.

Comment: Please add exception stacktrace and code, in which you are using the `Writable`.

Comment: @gyan Updated. Thanks!

Comment: The error is thrown by the reducer class. Please add code for `Reducer` class please.

Comment: @gyan edited. Sorry

Comment: Please add @Override on the `map()` function to eliminate the chances of default mapper's `map()` function getting called.

Comment: @gyan Yes it does have the Override keyword on it. But still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: You just need to remove your `WikiComparator` completely, and not call `job.setGroupingComparatorClass` at all.

**Explanation**:
The group comparator is intended to compare the map output keys, not the map output values. Your map output keys are `Text` objects and the values are `WikiWritable` objects.
This means that the bytes which are passed to your comparator for deserialisation represent serialised `Text` objects. However, the `WikiComparator` uses reflection to create `WikiWritable` objects (as instructed in its constructor), and then tries to deserialise the `Text` objects using the `WikiWritable.readFields` method. This obviously leads to wrong reading and consequently to the exception you see.

That said, I believe that you don't need a comparator at all, since the default `WritableComparator` does exactly what yours does: calls the `compareTo` method for the pair of objects that is passed to it.

EDIT: The `compareTo` method that is called is comparing your keys, not your values, so it compares `Text` objects. If you want to compare and sort your `WikiWritable`s you should consider adding them to a Composite Key. There are plenty of tutorials around on Composite Keys and secondary sorting.

Comment: @yzhan Also, your WikiPartitioner should extend `Partitioner<Text, WikiWritable>` (swapped). I didn't include this in the answer since it is not related to the EOFException.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, after removing `setGroupingComparatorClass`, the `compareTo` method never gets called at all so my sorting doesn't happen. Any solutions for this?

Comment: It doesn't call `compareTo` after I swapped the Partitioner pair too.

Comment: If you want to use a custom comparator, you can still do it, but your comparator should compare `Text` objects, because that is your map output key. Alternatively, you could use a Composite Key for secondary sorting (and set SortComparator plus GroupComparator).

Comment: @yzhan I just edited my answer to explain why your `compareTo` method is not called and possible alternative

Comment: Thanks. Looks like I had some misunderstanding about secondary sorting...All fixed now.